# Rails 3: A restful route for my English-French dictionary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, routes

A part of my website have an English-French dictionary. I want the url to be site.com/dictionary/:word. However, multiple words could be used to refer to one entry because there is the English word, the French word, and the male/female versions of the word.

I was able to get that to work in Rails 3 by using the following code.

```
# routes.rb
match 'dictionary/:word' => 'dictionary#show'
match 'dictionary' => 'dictionary#index', :as => :dictionary

# dictionary_controller.rb
def show
  @word = Dictionary.find( :first,
    :conditions => ['
      en_word_m = (?) or 
      en_word_f = (?) or
      fr_word_m = (?) or
      fr_word_f = (?)
    ',
    params[:word], params[:word], params[:word], params[:word]
    ]
  )
end
```

As you can see, the code is a little messy, and not very restful. It also makes the helpers for links a pain in the ass, and better off just using a hash instead. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Rest is about interacting with a resource. If the resource has many layers or aspects I do not say anything wrong with reflecting that in your routes:

```
dictionary/en-f/:word, :as => en_f_word
dictionary/en-m/:word, :as => en_m_word 
dictionary/fr-f/:word, :as => fr_f_word
dictionary/fr-m/:word, :as => fr_m_word
```

This has the advantage of reflecting the nature of the thing in the URL, and allowing much more descriptive helpers:

```
en_f__word_path(the_word)
```

If you wanted really descriptive helpers then wrap the above in a helper to give you:

```
path_to_french_feminine_word(word)
```

Also, :first has been deprecated in favour of:

```
Thing.first(:conditions => {:column => 'value'})
```

Answer (score 1):

This goes with Richard's answer somewhat.

If you ever expand to more than just french and english, you might define your route like this:

```
match "dictionary/:language-:sex/:word" => "dictionary#show", :as => "word"
```

Which will allow you pull off the language and sex you're trying to find from the params hash coming in.

You could then do some meta programming in your helpers to define methods for all the languages and sexes you support.